# Message: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource

Tags: java, node.js, appium, appium-android

I am starting appium server without using cmd and desktop app and for that I have written code but after running that code I got this exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 404. Message: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-SUFA48T', ip: '192.168.0.177'
Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.8.1'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:app=C:\Users\HP\Mobile Testing\MobileTestingAppium\src\test\java\resources\ApiDemos-debug.apk, appium:automationName=UiAutomator2, appium:deviceName=Pixel 2 API 28, platformName=ANDROID}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {app: C:\Users\HP\Mobile Testing\..., automationName: UiAutomator2, deviceName: Pixel 2 API 28, platformName: ANDROID}}]
Capabilities {}
```

I am using andriod emulator and running an app on it

[image: Andriod Emulator]

```
@Test
public void config() throws MalformedURLException {

    AppiumDriverLocalService service = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
            .withAppiumJS(
                    new File("C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js"))
            .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingPort(4723).withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(300)).build();

    service.start();

    // Construct the complete URL with the custom base path
    URL link = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Pixel 2 API 28");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,
            "C:\\Users\\HP\\Mobile Testing\\MobileTestingAppium\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\ApiDemos-debug.apk");
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2"); // for Android

    AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(link, capabilities);

    driver.quit();

}
```

This is my code

Please Solve this issue
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to call that API with a proper HTTP method using Postman or some other tool? Can you make sure that your code uses the acceptable HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.) that is supported by this specific API endpoint?

Comment: Yes i tried all working good , using cmd if i start appium server then its working

Comment: Inside your mobile device - what would "127.0.0.1:4723" mean? Would that service be running inside mobile? Or should you try to give your machine's IP where that service is running, and not the localhost/127.0.0.1?

Comment: "Thanks a ton, Ishan!" Solved this issue

Comment: Great. I will add that as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I made some changes in my code and custom base path (/wb/hub) which i did not add before

Answer (score 0):

Inside your mobile device - what would "127.0.0.1:4723" mean?
Would that service be running inside mobile? Or should you try to give your machine's IP where that service is running, and not the localhost/127.0.0.1?